# Can't perfom a simple hive request: select * from table_df

Tags: hive, parquet

I have created a hive table like this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE table_df (v1 String, v2 String, v3 String, v4 String, v5 String, v6 String, v7 String, v8 String, v9 String, v10 String, v11 String, v12 String, v13 String, v14 String, v15 String, v16 String, v17 String, v18 String, v19 String, v20 String, v21 String, v22 String, v23 String, v24 String, v25 String, v26 String, v27 String, v28 String, v29 String, v30 String, v31 String, v32 Double, v33 Int, v34 Int, v35 Int)
STORED AS PARQUET LOCATION '/data/test/table_df.parquet';
```

the parquet file has been :

```
root
 |-- v1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- v2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- v3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- v4: string (nullable = true)
 |-- v5: string (nullable = true)
 |-- v6: string (nullable = true)
 |-- v7: string (nullable = true)
 |-- v8: string (nullable = true)
 |-- v9: string (nullable = true)
 |-- v10: string (nullable = true)
 |-- v11: string (nullable = true)
 |-- v12: string (nullable = true)
 |-- v13: string (nullable = true)
 |-- v14: string (nullable = true)
 |-- v15: string (nullable = true)
 |-- v16: string (nullable = true)
 |-- v17: string (nullable = true)
 |-- v18: string (nullable = true)
 |-- v19: string (nullable = true)
 |-- v20: string (nullable = true)
 |-- v21: string (nullable = true)
 |-- v22: string (nullable = true)
 |-- v23: string (nullable = true)
 |-- v24: string (nullable = true)
 |-- v25: string (nullable = true)
 |-- v26: string (nullable = true)
 |-- v27: string (nullable = true)
 |-- v28: string (nullable = true)
 |-- v29: string (nullable = true)
 |-- v30: string (nullable = true)
 |-- v31: string (nullable = true)
 |-- v32: double (nullable = true)
 |-- v33: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- v34: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- v35: integer (nullable = true)
```

the problem occur when i perform this request

```
select * from table_df
```

and i get the following error message:

```
Bad status for request TFetchResultsReq(fetchType=0, operationHandle=TOperationHandle(hasResultSet=True, modifiedRowCount=None, operationType=0, operationId=THandleIdentifier(secret='b`a!2RA\xb7\x85\xb5u\xb5\x06\xe4,\x16', guid='\xcf\xbde\xc0\xc7%C\xe1\x9c\xf2\x10\x8d\xc1\xb2=\xec')), orientation=4, maxRows=100): TFetchResultsResp(status=TStatus(errorCode=0, errorMessage='java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot inspect org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.DoubleWritable', sqlState=None, infoMessages=['*org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot inspect org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.DoubleWritable:14:13', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation:getNextRowSet:SQLOperation.java:415', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.OperationManager:getOperationNextRowSet:OperationManager.java:233', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl:fetchResults:HiveSessionImpl.java:780', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService:fetchResults:CLIService.java:478', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService:FetchResults:ThriftCLIService.java:692', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$FetchResults:getResult:TCLIService.java:1557', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$FetchResults:getResult:TCLIService.java:1542', 'org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction:process:ProcessFunction.java:39', 'org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor:process:TBaseProcessor.java:39', 'org.apache.hive.service.auth.TSetIpAddressProcessor:process:TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:56', 'org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess:run:TThreadPoolServer.java:286', 'java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor:runWorker:ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142', 'java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker:run:ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617', 'java.lang.Thread:run:Thread.java:745', '*java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot inspect org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.DoubleWritable:16:2', 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchTask:fetch:FetchTask.java:164', 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver:getResults:Driver.java:1762', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation:getNextRowSet:SQLOperation.java:410', '*org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot inspect org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.DoubleWritable:23:7', 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ListSinkOperator:process:ListSinkOperator.java:93', 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator:forward:Operator.java:838', 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.SelectOperator:process:SelectOperator.java:88', 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Operator:forward:Operator.java:838', 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TableScanOperator:process:TableScanOperator.java:133', 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator:pushRow:FetchOperator.java:437', 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator:pushRow:FetchOperator.java:429', 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchTask:fetch:FetchTask.java:146', '*java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:Cannot inspect org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.io.DoubleWritable:28:5', 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.primitive.ParquetStringInspector:getPrimitiveJavaObject:ParquetStringInspector.java:77', 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.primitive.ParquetStringInspector:getPrimitiveJavaObject:ParquetStringInspector.java:28', 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.ObjectInspectorUtils:copyToStandardObject:ObjectInspectorUtils.java:305', 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils:toThriftPayload:SerDeUtils.java:168', 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchFormatter$ThriftFormatter:convert:FetchFormatter.java:61', 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ListSinkOperator:process:ListSinkOperator.java:90'], statusCode=3), results=None, hasMoreRows=None)
```

I have no problem with this request:

```
   select v1 from table_df
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Did you find the solution? im having the same issue

Comment: Does /data/test/table_df.parquet exist? What does it contain? Did you put it there?

Answer (score 3):

This happens because the files that this table pointing to does not have the same format as the table structure. Check the tables properties using 'show create table *table_name*'

and make sure the HDFS file (that this table is pointing) satisfies those properties including number of columns and column types.

Comment: make sure the HDFS file (that this table is pointing) satisfies those properties including number of columns and column types.- Agree!